# Someone please explain select/options for forms in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Alright, yes I am an idiot. I have a decent amount of experience with rails but I cannot get select options to function the way I want it to.

All I want is a simple select dropdown for `:experience` with the following values:

```
'Experience...'  Value: 0
'Beginner'       Value: 1
'Advanced'       Value: 2
'Expert'         Value: 3
```

For the life of me, I can't get the value to save in the database. Any help much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: would you mind posting your "show" code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can just do something like:

```
<%= f.select(:experience, [["Experience", 0], ["Beginner",1], ["Advanced", 2], ["Expert", 3]]) %>
```

EDIT 2: Took the options tag back out (must be optional itself now) and we'll keep it simple.

Comment: Gracias! Perfect. Thank you. Knew it was easy :P -- Will accept in '4 minutes' -- still don't get why s.o. makes you wait.

Comment: Thanks and glad to help! I was actually stuck on the same problem a few days ago- usually I pull the values from the database (much more documented), but needed to define my own in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Generally I proceed as follows:

in my view

```
<%= f.select(:name,  MyModel::CONSTANT, {:include_blank => 'Select...'}) %>
```

in my model:

```
CONSTANT= [["Experience", 0], ["Beginner",1]]
```

It's important to keep data separated between model and view.

Comment: SO I would place the CONSTANT statement in my associated model?

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Justin. You could also:

```
@levels = ['Experience', 'Beginner', 'Advanced', 'Expert']

<%= f.select(:experience, @levels.map {|level| [level, @levels.index(level)] }) %>
```